# Google one-tap sign-in stopped working. Possibly related to FedCM changes?

Tags: google-signin, fedcm

Google one-tap stopped working. Console shows:
[GSI_LOGGER]: The given login_uri is not allowed for the given client ID.
Login for this site has been up and running for years, including as recently as yesterday.

Not sure if it's related, but we received an email last month indicating that the site would be migrating to FedCM in April. The email also indicated that no issues were detected so we could expect it to be seamless.

We are seeing the login failures on both of the sites in the OAuth project.

I've now followed the [migration doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/fedcm-migration), adding `data-use_fedcm_for_prompt="true"` to the `g_id_onload` block but no luck. The email indicated we could postpone the migration by setting that value to `false` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I see the same problem starting about 16 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it seems that you didn't correctly set up Authorized redirect URIs value in Google Cloud console. See [data-login_url](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-login_uri) and step 5 on this [page](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid#get_your_google_api_client_id).

Thanks,
Herman

Comment: It's configured correctly; the site has been working for years with the defined url redirect. This behavior started today.

Comment: Actually, you are correct. The behavior changed and the full URL is now required, e.g., `https://myhost.com/login`. Before this, the trailing `/login` wasn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `redirect_uri` behavior changed. The configured "Redirect URIs" had to be updated to include the full path, e.g., `https://myhost.com/login`. Before this, the trailing `/login` wasn't required. Hope this helps.